# Visual block shift-i(nsert) in VsVim

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vsvim

In GVim on Linux I am used to being able to do Ctrl-V then I type whatever I want at the beginning of the first line, hit Esc and then Vim will insert whatever I typed to every row. I have tried this on VsVim, in Visual Studio, using Ctrl-Q, instead of Ctrl-V, but `I` does nothing. Is there any way to reproduce this functionality in VsVim?

I'm fairly certain it has nothing to do with my .vimrc file.

Comment: Did you have a plugin?  My GVim doesn't do that (v7.2)

Comment: I looked into it a bit more, vim needs to be compiled with +visualextra to do it. I use my package manager to install and update it, and I use the bleeding edge version, maybe that's it? Could also be my package manager compiles it with that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block insertion has been added to VsVim 1.2. I just tested it and it works.

[VsVim 1.2 Release Notes](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/Release-Notes)

Comment: I'm personally really looking forward to the fix; I'd like to be able to comment out blocks like this instead of falling back to the VS shortcut.

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing it out. I don't do much in Visual Studio these days anymore, most of my work is on Linux and I use GVim as my goto editor, so it was nice to find VsVim, but I really miss the block insert.

Comment: I edited the answer to show that this works in VsVim as of version 1.2.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for updating this. I use Visual Studio even less nowadays, it's not even installed at the moment, but I'm sure this will help someone at some point